# Using geoJSON in mongoose schema and use it in a query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

I'm new to mongoDB and the usage of geoJSON within it.

I have the following schema I created using the mongoose module:

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');

var hikeSchema = mongoose.Schema({

  name: String,
  area: String,
  length: Number,
  time: String,
  Difficulty: { type : Number, min : 0 , max :5 },
  start_coord: {
    lon: Number,
    lat: Number
  },
  rank_count: Number,
  avg_overall_rating: { type : Number, min : 0 , max :5 },
  completed_count: Number,
  description: String,
  ranking_pages: [
    mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
  ]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Hike', hikeSchema);
```

I used a simple `Number` type to represent to longitude and latitude inside a sub object within the schema.

I don't know if this is the way to go about it. I want it to be saved as a geoJSON object and then run queries on this object.

Answer (score 3):

I recommand you to see the mongoDB part for geolocation datas : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2d/

To store longitude, latitude, MongoDB take you the correct data structure to save items :

> To store location data as legacy coordinate pairs, use an array or an embedded document. 
>   When possible, use the array format:
>
> > loc : [ < longitude > , < latitude > ]
>
> Consider the embedded document form:
>
> > loc : { lng :  , lat :  }
>
> Arrays are preferred as certain languages do not guarantee associative map ordering.
>
> For all points, if you use longitude and latitude, store coordinates in longitude, latitude order.

On your shema, change

```
start_coord: {
  lon: Number,
  lat: Number
},
```

By :

```
start_coord: {
  lng: Number,
  lat: Number
},
```

Then you should add a 2dindex for your field `start_coords` to use  all mongoDB geospatial queries :

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { start_coord : "2d" } , { min : <l ower bound > , max : < upper bound > } )
```

**EDIT** It's important to set min and max if your longitude and latitude is not a real lng/lat (for example if you could use 2dindexes in a orthonormal map)

Now you can use all geospatial query operators : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-geospatial/

Comment: That's good for legacy pairs but you can also use [GeoJSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/#geojson-objects). GeoJSON has better support for spherical computations. If your hikes are short enough, it won't matter much if you use 2d or 2dsphere computations.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it this way:

```
start_coord: {
    type: [Number],   // [<longitude>, <latitude>]
    index: '2d'   // create the geospatial index
}
```

Check this tutorial: [How to use geospatial indexing in mongoDb](http://blog.robertonodi.me/how-to-use-geospatial-indexing-in-mongodb-using-express-and-mongoose/)